# Can't get atmosphere working in scene after following a tutorial

Tags: rendering, shaders, compositing-nodes

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3cmw.jpg

Above is an image of what I have set up, I'm also running Eevee. My goal is to get a look like this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBsym.jpg

For some reason it is waayyyyy to bright and I start getting random artifacts when I render my scenes, on top of that my scenes are always different; as in the artifacts and lighting always change.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please use the built-in image upload system.

Comment: Also, please add your blend file to your question.